# How to get vector a from known inner product?

Tags: vector, products, coefficients

Assuming that `a.b=z`,where `b={b1,b2,b3}` and `z=x b1+y b2+z b3`, obviously `a={x,y,z}`, how to realize it by mathematica?

Comment: dnvin, welcome to mma.se. Our standard welcome message: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) If you haven't already done so please take  [the tour!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)  ...

Comment: ... 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking [the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a.{b1,b2,b3} == x b1+y b2+z b3` ***for all*** `{b1,b2,b3}`:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{b1, b2, b3}, Dot[{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}] == x b1 + y b2 + z b3]]
```

> a3 == z && a2 == y && a1 == x

or

```
SolveAlways[ Dot[{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}] == x b1 + y b2 + z b3, {b1, b2, b3}]
```

> {{a1 -> x, a2 -> y, a3 -> z}}

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I want.

Comment: @dnvin, my pleasure. Welcome mma.se.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you have a single linear equation with 3 unknowns.

It's not possible to back out the 3 unknown values. You have an equation for a 3D hyperplane with an infinite number of solutions.